# how to filtering collectionvew cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionview cell, and need to filtering cell.

I'm trying to make cell height to 0. but not work.

this is my code.

extension ViewController:  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return self.numberOfCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? data else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
            
    let set1 = CoreDataManager.shared.getSetting(idx: indexPath.row).set1
    
    if(set1){
    
    return cell
    }
    else{
        let none = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "none", for: indexPath)
        none.frame.size.width =  100
        none.frame.size.height =  CGSize(width: 0, height: 100).width
        return none

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't filter a collection view by making the cell size to `.zero`, you filter a cell by updating the data source, the array that you use to tell how many sections there are, how many rows there are per section, what model use into cellForItemAt...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set a size of cell you need to conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and implement sizeForItemAt and give it the size.

```
extension viewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 0)}
}
```

another solution to make height constrain for a view inside the your cell with identifier "cell" and give it to 0 before returning a cell in cellForItemAt.